# Some characters in CSV file are not read during PHP fgetcsv()

Tags: php, csv

I am reading a CSV file with php. Many of the rows have a "check mark" which is really the square root symbol: √ and the php code is just skipping over this character every time it is encountered.

Here is my code (printing to the browser window in "CSV style" format so I can check that the lines break at the right place:

```
$file = fopen($uploadfile, 'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
   foreach ($line as $key => $value) {
    if ($value) {
       echo $value.",";
    }
   }
   echo "<br />";
}
fclose($file);
```

As an interim solution, I am just finding and replacing the checkmarks with 1's manually, in Excel. Obviously I'd like a more efficient solution :) Thanks for the help!

Comment: I've had plenty of problems using `fgetcsv()` in the past. When I run into these types of issues I usually start parsing the file manually. =\

Comment: There are known bugs with fgetcsv() and non-ASCII characters, particularly at the beginning of unquoted values.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238971/fgetcsv-ignores-special-characters-when-they-are-at-the-beginning-of-line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fgetcsv() only works on standard ASCII characters; so it's probably "correct" in skipping your square root symbols.  However, rather than replacing the checkmarks manually, you could read the file into a string, do a str_replace() on those characters, and then parse it using fgetcsv().  You can turn a string into a file pointer (for fgetcsv) thusly:

```
$fp = fopen('php://memory', 'rw');
fwrite($fp, (string)$string);
rewind($fp);
while (($line = fgetcsv($fp)) !== FALSE)
...
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with accented first characters of strings. I eventually gave up on fgetscv and did the following, using `fgets()` and `explode()` instead (I'm guessing your csv is comma separated):

```
$file = fopen($uploadfile, 'r');

while (($the_line = fgets($file)) !== FALSE)  // <-- fgets
{
  $line = explode(',', $the_line);            // <-- explode
  foreach ($line as $key => $value) 
  {
    if ($value) 
    {
      echo $value.",";
    }
  }
  echo "<br />";
}

fclose($file);
```

Comment: I have a question about this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836653/php-fgetcsv-not-reading-first-utf-8-caracter-alternatif-using-fgets

Answer (score 0):

You should *setlocale* ar written in documentation

> **Note:**
>   Locale setting is taken into account by this function. If LANG is e.g. en_US.UTF-8, files     in one-byte encoding are read wrong by this function.

before *fgetcsv* add setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8'). In my case it was 'lt_LT.UTF-8'.

This behaviour is reported as a [php bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48507)