# fgetcsv() drops characters with diacritics (i.e. non-ASCII) - how to fix?

Tags: php, csv, character-encoding

> **Similar questions:**
>   [Some characters in CSV file are not read during PHP fgetcsv()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472886/some-characters-in-csv-file-are-not-read-during-php-fgetcsv) ,
>   [fgetcsv() ignores special characters when they are at the beginning of line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238971/php-fgetcsv-ignores-special-characters-when-they-are-at-the-beginning-of-line)

My application has a form where the users can upload a CSV file (its 5 internal users have always uploaded a valid file - comma-delimited, quoted, records end by LF), and the file is then imported into a database using PHP:

```
$fhandle = fopen($uploaded_file,'r');
while($row = fgetcsv($fhandle, 0, ',', '"', '\\')) {
    print_r($row);
    // further code not relevant as the data is already corrupt at this point
}
```

For reasons I cannot change, the users are uploading the file encoded in the `Windows-1250` charset - a single-byte, 8-bit character encoding.

The problem: and *some* (not all!) characters beyond 127 ("extended ASCII") are dropped in `fgetcsv()`. Example data:

```
"15","Ústav"
"420","Špičák"
"7","Tmaň"
```

becomes

```
Array (
  0 => 15
  1 => "stav"
)
Array (
  0 => 420
  1 => "pičák"
)
Array (
  0 => 7
  1 => "Tma"
)
```

(Note that `č` is kept, but `Ú` is dropped)

The documentation for [fgetcsv](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) says that "since 4.3.5   fgetcsv() is now binary safe", but looks like it isn't. Am I doing something wrong, or is this function broken and I should look for a different way to parse CSV?

Comment: I'll answer right away, this bug has bitten me earlier and have found the cause; wanted to share this with SO, as the bug is *subtle*.

Comment: (just to clarify, Win-1250 is just the input encoding. The data is later converted and stored in database as UTF-8; that part works OK. The initial data read was the problem.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It turns out that I didn't read the documentation well enough - fgetcsv() is only *somewhat* binary-safe. It is safe for plain ASCII < 127, but [the documentation also says](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php):

> Note:
>
> Locale setting is taken into account
>   by this function. If LANG is e.g.
>   en_US.UTF-8, files in one-byte
>   encoding are read wrong by this
>   function

In other words, **fgetcsv() tries to be binary-safe, but it's actually not** (because it's also messing with the charset at the same time), and it will probably mangle the data it reads (as this setting is not configured in php.ini, but rather read from `$LANG`).

I've sidestepped the issue by reading the lines with `fgets` (which works on bytes, not characters) and using [a CSV function from the comment in the docs](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php#98800) to parse them into an array:

```
$fhandle = fopen($uploaded_file,'r');
while($raw_row = fgets($fhandle)) { // fgets is actually binary safe
    $row = csvstring_to_array($raw_row, ',', '"', "\n");
    // $row is now read correctly
}
```

Comment: errors : fgets lenght must be greater to 0 and csvstring_to_array does not exist

Comment: not error: of course it doesn't exist if it's not defined - it needs to be defined explicitly, it's not built-in. "using a CSV function from the comment" and a link to it is not clear?