# Swedish csv file encoding problems

Tags: php, csv, encoding

The Swedish alphabet contains the letters

> åäö

I try to read a csv file with the PHP function [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) but I get encoding problems and the special characters are not correctly interpreted.

I open the file with [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) ( $filePath, "r" ) and I do not speciay any encoding that anywhere in PHP that I am aware of. Everything else in my application works fine regarding to encoding.

When I open the target csv file in open office suite I can select encoding. If I select Unicode(UTF-8) the special characters can not be displayed. If I select some ISO-8859, the letters are correctly displayed.

I have been playing around with  utf8_decode,  utf8_encode, mb_convert_encoding, iconv and setlocale with no luck.

I know what encoding is but I do not understand this case. It would be nice with a solution and a good explanation of what is going on here.

I guess my file is ISO-8859-* encoded

> How can I parse the file correctly so I can make use of its content in
>   PHP?

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this
    Å

    &Aring;

    å

    &aring;

    Ä

    &Auml;

    ä

    &auml;

    Ö

    &Ouml;

    ö

    &ouml;
```

Answer (score 1):

you could encoded your file, for example using [htmlentities](https://php.net//manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

for example, with this litle code, i encoded the swedish file to ISO-8859-1,

```
$file = fopen("translations-sv.csv", "r");
$new_file = fopen("file_encoded.csv", "w");
while(!feof($file)) {

$line=fgets($file);
$line = str_replace(";", ",",$line);  //replace all ';' to ','
$encoded_line=htmlentities($line,ENT_QUOTES,'ISO-8859-1');

fwrite($new_file, $encoded_line);
}

fclose($file);
fclose($new_file);
```

Swedish.csv

```
title_orders;Beställningar
title_monthly_sales;Månadsförsäljning
title_settings;Inställningar
```

file_encoded.csv

```
title_orders,Best&Atilde;&curren;llningar
title_monthly_sales,M&Atilde;&yen;nadsf&Atilde;&para;rs&Atilde;&curren;ljning
title_settings,Inst&Atilde;&curren;llningar
```

and, to compare,

```
$new_file = fopen("file_encoded.csv", "r");

$word_to_find="Orderslutf&Atilde;&para;rande";
while (!feof($new_file) ) {

    $line_of_text = fgetcsv($new_file, 1024,",");
if($word_to_find==$line_of_text[1]) 
 echo $line_of_text[1]." is the same to $word_to_find<br>";
}
fclose($new_file);
```

Comment: How can I use the resulting file_encoded.csv in PHP to parse the file and compare to strings like artikelbenämning? This becomes Artikelben&iuml
&iquest
&frac12
mning and is hence not equal to artikelbenäming. I also get problems because of the ";". Thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637770/why-fgetcsv-drops-some-characters-with-diacritics

Comment: what is the delimiter in your original csv file? if are ";" there would be a problem, becouse of the htmlentities, i didnt saw it...

Comment: Yes it is ; :(. I cannot beleve that this is such a problem. Some people says that you should just put env(Lang... or set locate but it does not work either

Comment: it gets encoded like this: Artikelben&iuml;&iquest;&frac12;mning but its not useful since it is not == Artikelbenäming. I want to opbtain the strings correctly for this to be useful. It may be printed as Artikelbenämning in html but I do not know

Comment: I solved this by modifying the CSV file itself, thanks for the help annyway:) I now have other encoding problems...