# Greek characters problem in fgetcsv?

Tags: php, csv

When i split a csv file with my php script i can not see the greek language characters! Could you please help me to convert them? data will be saved in the csv.

```
<?
$path="book.csv";
if (($handle = fopen("$path", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($info = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    print_r($info);
    echo "<br>";
  }
}
?>
```

[DEMO](http://galtech.org/test/csv/testcsv.php)

the question mark is actually the greek words. please help me 
thank you

Comment: What is the codepage of the Source CSV ?

Comment: What is the charset of your CSV file?

Comment: http://galtech.org/test/csv/book.csv i didn't specify any charset

Comment: You made a mistake saving that .csv file. When the export dialog comes up, select the UTF-8 charset.

Comment: Confirm. the CSV file does not contain Greek. The question marks are just that : 0x3F ASCII

Comment: There are known bugs with fgetcsv() and non-ASCII characters, particularly at the beginning of unquoted values.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238971/fgetcsv-ignores-special-characters-when-they-are-at-the-beginning-of-line

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the correct charset in the content-type HTTP header - which is the same charset the CSV has been saved with. You can also convert the csv data from the original encoding to UTF-8 using `mb_convert_string` or `iconv`.