# problem with fgetcsv( ) and Unicode

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

i have a  code. 
on localhost i have not problem with reading csv file (with Unicode chars). but when upload code on host  output is nothing. why? what is solution?

```
while (($data=fgetcsv($fin,5000,","))!==FALSE) 
{
 var_dump($data[0]);  //on host output is `string(0) ""` but on local i can see output
 var_dump($data[1]);  //$data[1] is integer and  i can see output
}
```

Comment: can you read on the file? maybe not enough permission to do a read file

Comment: do an fopen on $fin and let us know the result

Comment: There are known bugs with fgetcsv() and non-ASCII characters, particularly at the beginning of unquoted values: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238971/fgetcsv-ignores-special-characters-when-they-are-at-the-beginning-of-line

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **Note:**
>
> Locale setting is taken into account by this function. If LANG is e.g. en_US.UTF-8, files in one-byte encoding are read wrong by this function.

http://php.net/fgetcsv

One possible solution is to use [`setlocale()`](http://php.net/set_locale).

Answer (score 2):

One such thing is the occurrence of the UTF byte order mark, or BOM. The UTF-8 character for the byte order mark is U+FEFF, or rather three bytes – 0xef, 0xbb and 0xbf – that sits in the beginning of the text file. For UTF-16 it is used to indicate the byte order. For UTF-8 it is not really necessary.

So you need to detect the three bytes and remove the BOM. Below is a simplified example on how to detect and remove the three bytes.

```
$str = file_get_contents('file.utf8.csv');
$bom = pack("CCC", 0xef, 0xbb, 0xbf);
if (0 == strncmp($str, $bom, 3)) {
    echo "BOM detected - file is UTF-8\n";
    $str = substr($str, 3);
}
```

That's all

Comment: Would mb_detect_encoding catch this?

Answer (score 1):

I used iconv for unicode encoding, and it works almost perfect in my situation. I hope it will help someone else too.

```
$csvFile = fopen('file/path', "r");
fgetcsv($csvFile);
while(($row = fgetcsv($csvFile, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE){        
  for ($c=0; $c < count($row); $c++) {
    echo iconv( "Windows-1252", "UTF-8", $row[$c]);
  }
}
fclose($csvFile);
```