# Hebrew letters ignored selectively by fgetcsv

Tags: php, wordpress, excel, csv, encoding

I'm trying to read a CSV file in Hebrew in order to insert multiple posts to Wordpress.
I've saved the excel sheet as CSV (coma delimited).
After some encoding manipulation in Sublime Text, I see the Hebrew content normally in any text editor.

However, when I try to read the contents of the file using `fgetcsv` the Hebrew letters are being ignored selectively, i.e the letters in the field which are preceded with either a number or a Latin letter, ARE showing correctly. Hebrew Letters *before* the number/Latin letter are ignored and omitted from the output.

If I use `file_get_contents` and var_dump it, I get the entire content correctly, so it stands to reason that the problem lies with `fgetcsv`.

Code in `functions.php`:

```
function csv_to_array($filename='', $delimiter=',')
{
    if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename)) {
        return FALSE;
        }

    $header = NULL;
    $data = array();

    if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)
    {
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
        {
            if(!$header): 
                $header = $row;
            else:
                $data[] = $row;
            endif;
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

used:

```
if (isset($_FILES['events'])) {
    extract($_FILES['events']);
    $events = csv_to_array($tmp_name);
```

Comment: So how exactly is the CSV file encoded now?

Comment: I re-opened it in Sublime with ISO 8859-8 and then saved it as UTF-8. If I open it directly as UTF-8 I get question marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very likely that the language that gave the world `T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM` has now problems with Hebrew letters ;-).

[Checking the encoding of the strings](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) (`var_dump` might not be enough!) and Manvel's solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882090/utf-8-problems-while-reading-csv-file-with-fgetcsv) might be of help to you:

> The problem is that the function returns UTF-8 (it can check using
>   `mb_detect_encoding`), but **do not convert**, and these characters
>   take UTF-8. Тherefore, it's necessary to do the reverse-convert to
>   initial encoding (Windows-1251 or CP1251) using [iconv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php). But since
>   `fgetcsv` returns an array, I suggest to write a custom function:
>
> ```
> function customfgetcsv(&$handle, $length, $separator = ';'){
>   if(($buffer = fgets($handle, $length)) !== false) {
>       return explode( $separator, iconv( "CP1251", "UTF-8", $buffer ) );
>   }
>     return false;
> }
> ```

Comment: I ended up using a different custom function: I read the whole content as a string and exploded it twice - by EOL and by comma.