# htmlspecialchars remove the value inside the array?

Tags: php, mongodb, csv, encoding, export-to-csv

So I'm uploading a csv file. One of the column have a single quote.

```
145 Test St'
```

The array is

```
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 20
    [2] => 145 Test St�
    [3] => Test City
    [4] => 1455
    [5] => 919749797
)
```

As you can see. Instead of single quote ( **'** ), it becomes �.

From here, I use **htmlspecialchars($row)**, which gives the result.

```
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 20
    [2] => 
    [3] => Test City
    [4] => 1455
    [5] => 919749797
)
```

First question, why ( ' ) becomes ( � ) ?

Second question, why after using **htmlspecialchars()**, the value disappear?

Third question, How can I retain the ( **'** ) ?

Thanks for those who can answer.

EDIT:

```
  $row  = array_map('str_getcsv', file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));
        $csv  = Array();
        $head = $row[0];
        $col  = count($row[0]);
        unset($row[0]);

        pre($row[1]);

        $row[1] = array_map('htmlentities', $row[1]);

        pre($row[1]);
```

EDIT:

**pre()** is a function I created that works like

```
<pre></pre>.
```

EDIT:

I've look at the CSV file using file --mime at the terminal. It's charset is **unknown 8-bit**. I convert the CSV file to UTF-8 by doing a save as. After that I manage to upload the CSV file successfully. The problem is on the encoding of the CSV file.

Is it possible to convert the file into UTF-8?

Comment: the file is utf8?, or you read file use utf8? can you show your code? thanks

Comment: @lighter what file? the csv?

Comment: yes csv file, and can you show your read file code?

Comment: Sorry, but how to know if a csv file is utf8? I'll update my question wait..

Comment: can you paste the definition of pre()? otherwise is hard to answer to your question :)

Comment: Sorry!! haha. pre() is actually a function I created. It works similar with <pre> to see the value of array easily. But don't mind it.

Comment: you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/26529332/685060

Answer (score 0):

According to php.net's [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) page :

"If the input string contains an invalid code unit sequence within the given encoding an empty string will be returned, unless either the ENT_IGNORE or ENT_SUBSTITUTE flags are set."

So the solution is: use "$variable = htmlspecialchars( $string, ENT_IGNORE);"
You can create a function with "htmlspecialchars" and array map that function like this -

```
function specialchars($string){
    return htmlspecialchars( $string, ENT_IGNORE);
}


$row  = array_map('str_getcsv', file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));
$csv  = Array();
$head = $row[0];
$col  = count($row[0]);
unset($row[0]);
pre($row[1]);
$row[1] = array_map('specialchars', $row[1]);
pre($row[1]);
```

Comment: This delete the single quote. I need to retain the single quote.

Comment: I've guessed your php (which read the csv file) file is not utf-8 formatted and it is still using ISO-8859-1 format instead. Convert your php file as UTF-8 without BOM with your prior code. If it it will not works then let me know.