# How to parse csv data and insert in database using php codeigniter

Tags: php, csv, mysqli, codeigniter-3

This is view

```
 <form method="post" action = "<?php echo site_url('Welcome/csvfile');?>" 
 enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="csvfileread" required accept=".csv,.xlsx">
 <input type="submit" name="submit">
 </form>
```

This is my controller

```
public function csvfile()
{   
    $this->load->library('CSVReader');

    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        $csv = $_FILES['csvfileread']['tmp_name'];

        $opencsv = fopen($csv,"r");
        while (($row = fgetcsv($opencsv, 10000, ",")) != FALSE) 
        {
            print_r($row); 

            $sql = "INSERT into data (id,name) VALUES('', '".addslashes($row[0])."')  ";
            $this->db->query($sql);
        }
    }
}
```

Data gets inserted but then it is encrypted how to put parsed data in database? My excel sheet contains 25 rows...how to access data of those rows? and insert accordingly in database...the database above is dummy database.

output of $row

```
     Array ( [0] => PK!������[Content_Types].xml 
     ��(��T�n�0�W�?D�V�@���8t9�H�0�@ [1] => 
      �����PP��H4zI��o�g'�mYDh�M� �l洱 
     �T��^z�"BRV��YH�P�G�W�l�#^m19���J���`��R? 
     ���*s�D��$��%��襤�`�)qm��.��c�uy� � ������O  
     /�c)�wڇ��b� 
     ��PK!K�_qxl/workbook.xml�R�N�0}7���K�� 
     l$F����z��vi����vd����=�g��n�<6�| 
     �u��ƣ�ХR�r��~��R�<ׂ+�!�'ptY�� [1] => :c��� )
```

Comment: show what is output of $row

Comment: that is also encrypted. @pradeep

Comment: if data get inserted but then its encrypted then the problem is with the type of data you are inserting not your code.

Comment: data is normal text @ChukwuemekaIhedoro

Comment: check this out, it might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882090/utf-8-problems-while-reading-csv-file-with-fgetcsv @aakankshakhandelwal

Comment: that is very much confusing..but then too will try

Comment: Um, excel? You did remember to save the file as a text/csv? Just changing the extension won't change the contents. And welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: yes i did that only..my file was in .xlsx extension ! Just after changing file extension it worked. @J.Martin

Comment: Excellent :) I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Converted .xlsx file to .csv file.