# Problem with UTF-16LE characters reading csv with php

Tags: php, csv

I have a php script that reads a csv file (it has UTF-16LE encoding).
The problem is that at some lines the array of php reading the lines of the csv is collapsed because of some Greek characters.
A example is bellow (there are 7 elements at the array and the bellow has only 2), how can I solve this problem?

> Array  (
> [0] => 205198
> [1] => Label 4.2 Βάση για Σ▒  )

My code is bellow

```
$array = file_get_contents($this->listUrl);      
         $array = mb_convert_encoding($array, 'UTF8', 'UTF-16LE');   // Convert the file to UTF8
         $array = preg_split("/\R/", $array);                        // Split it by line breaks       
         $array = array_map(function ($v) {
             return str_getcsv($v, ";");
         }, $array);
```

[edit]I used the code below

```
$array = str_getcsv($array, "\n");
        foreach ($array as &$Row) {
            $Row = str_getcsv($Row, ";");          
        }
```

Comment: This _should_ rather be done using `fgetcsv` with proper locale set (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6160934/1427878) - if you _just_ split by line breaks, you risk messing up your data, if any of the cell _values_ could ever contain a line break.

Comment: @CBroe , it seems that you are right. I use the code below
 $f = file_get_contents('file');     
        $f = mb_convert_encoding($f, 'UTF8', 'UTF-16LE');   
        $f = str_getcsv($f, "\n");
 foreach($f as &$Row) 
        {
            $Row = str_getcsv($Row, ";");     
                             
        }

Answer (score 0):

*My best bet is that :*

*You need **mb_split**, since you are messing with **multibyte** **strings** to support GR lang.*

***Some theory :***

> UTF-8, with the famous ASCII = 1 byte.
>
> UTF-16 with all unicode characters support = 4 bytes.

***Some action :***

"mb_split — Split multibyte string using regular expression" :
[PHP : mb_split](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-split.php)

There are also similar functions as **mb_ereg_replace**.

***Example :***

```
$array = file_get_contents($this->listUrl);      
         $array = mb_convert_encoding($array, 'UTF8', 'UTF-16LE');   // Convert the file to UTF8
         $array = mb_split("/\R/", $array);                        // Split it by line breaks       
         $array = array_map(function ($v) {
             return str_getcsv($v, ";");
         }, $array);
```

Have fun !